# get some ascii value having KEY character using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm making connect to http server.

Server have specific authkey.
Value is date and word. I convert ascii to string.
I get some value. It looks invisible.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVS2t.png]

#### string value XOR operation

e.g) "Mon Jan 08 2018" ^ "aoenthus-2c'\''34pnq"'

```
QString  auth_key= getXorEncryptDecrypt("Mon Jan 08 2018","aoenthus-2c'34pnq");

QString Test::getXorEncryptDecrypt(const char* str, const char* key)
{
  QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("utf-8");
  QByteArray byte = codec->fromUnicode(str);

  QString new_key;

  int nSize = byte.size();

  for(int i=0; i < nSize; i++){
      byte[i] = byte[i] ^ key[i];

      qDebug() << i << byte[i];
  }


   std::string strUtf8 = codec->toUnicode(byte).toStdString();

   QString auth_key = convertKey(strUtf8);

   qDebug() <<  auth_key;

   return auth_key;
}

QString Test::convertKey(std::string inputString)
{

    // check ascii code
     int i = 0;

    QString new_key;
    for (std::string::iterator it=inputString.begin(); it!=inputString.end(); ++it,++i)
    {
       //a -z ,A-Z, " > '  white space
        if (((*it) >= 0x61 && (*it) <= 0x7a) ||         //a-z
            ((*it) >= 0x41 && (*it) <= 0x5a) ||     // A- Z
            ((*it) == 0x22  || (*it) == 0x3e ||  (*it) ==0x27)  //"  >  '
             || ((*it) == 0x20 ||(*it) == 0x09)
             || (*it) == 0x2C
              || (*it) ==0x0B || (*it) == 0x1B || (*it) == 0x1D
              || (*it) ==0x15 || (*it) == 0x03 || (*it) == 0x05) //VT

        {
           new_key.append(*it);
            }

       }

        return new_key;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're dealing with non printable (invisible) characters. I suggest to keep the encrypted byte array in a hex encoded string. I also suggest you to check if the key string is shorter than the string to encrypt (a common workaround is to double the key string until its length is equal or greater than the data length).

```
QString Test::getXorEncryptDecrypt(const char* str, const char* key)
{
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("utf-8");
    QByteArray byte = codec->fromUnicode(str);

    int nSize = byte.size();

    QString keystring(key);
    while(keystring.size() < nSize)
    {
        keystring += keystring;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<nSize; i++){

        byte[i] = byte[i] ^ keystring.at(i).toLatin1();
    }

    return byte.toHex();
}

int main()
{
    QString  auth_key= getXorEncryptDecrypt("Mon Jan 08 2018","aoenthus-2c'34pnq");
    qDebug() << auth_key; //"2c000b4e3e091b531d0a4315030548"
}
```

To retrieve the raw bytes from the hex-encoded string:

```
QByteArray byte = QByteArray::fromHex(hex_encoded);
```